# How to read an .xlsx file downloaded from internet which is in protected view using Apache poi in java?

Tags: java, apache-poi, apache-poi-4

I have a requirement to download a .XLSX file from some website and place it on Java server , then read the file using java code.
 But not able to read .XLSX file in java which is downloaded from internet as file is in protected view?  I am using poi 4.1.

Comment: You need to give more detail on *exactly* what you're attempting and what you have tried to expect to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of the .xlsx file using OutputStream and then access the contents of the .xlsx file

Answer (score 0):

You can still access the file through Apache poi if .xlsx is in protected mode.